# New line in Full Calendar description

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, newline, popper.js

I am building a website and I am using Full Calendar to integrate a schedule with descriptions when one hovers over an event. But the problem is I am not able to make a new line in the description if I use \n. Is there a way to get around this?

The link to my code via Codepen is below. If you look under events and then the descriptions you can see the `LINE ONE \n LINE TWO` code I put in. That is the part that is not working.

Here is my code: https://codepen.io/jjaacckk/pen/ReEyPr

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, the `content` option of a Bootstrap /popper.js popover is treated as plain text. Another thing to note is that since we're in a HTML document, a newline character is not use to us. So you need to change two small things:

1. As per the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#options) set the `html` option to `true` so that it will treat anything you insert into the title or content as HTML instead of plain text.

   ```
   html: true,
   ```
2. Insert a HTML line break into your description instead of the newline character.

   description: 'LINE ONE 
    LINE TWO'

So overall your JS code would look like this:

```
$(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'month',
    defaultDate: '2018-10-12',

    eventRender: function(eventObj, $el) {
      $el.popover({
        title: eventObj.title,
        content: eventObj.description,
        trigger: 'hover',
        html: true,
        placement: 'top',
        container: 'body'
      });
    },

    events: [
      {
        title: 'EVENT 1',
        description: 'LINE ONE <br> LINE TWO',
        start: '2018-10-01'
      }
    ]
  });

});
```

Comment: this didn't work for me it just renders the <br> has normal

Comment: @ReedJones something must be different in your environment then, compared to what worked here. Ask a new question about it, if you're stuck. Link to it here and I could take a look. be sure to provide enough code etc to allow us to reproduce your situation.

Comment: the problem was that the library includes some css that changes the word-wrap or white-space css property, I was able to fix it using css, but noted that neither '\n' or \<br>' worked for me